# conn.GetSchema find primary key of table - MsAccess

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have a MsAccess database (**.mdb**) located in D drive as (*D:\project.mdb*).
Database have more than 120 Tables. There is a table *Records* which have primary key and multiple fields. I want to get the Columns,ColumnType and PrimaryKey.

I am getting fields and its type using :

```
Dim TableNm_ As String = "Records"      
Dim restrictions2() As String = {Nothing, Nothing, TableNm_, Nothing} 
Dim DataTable2 As System.Data.DataTable = conn.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions2)
```

But it did not have PrimayKey Column.

I have gone through several SO posts and others like [GetSchema and PrimaryKey column](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d58687c9-bb35-4f5f-ba81-52cd7fceab70/getschema-and-primarykeys-getting-primary-key-column-name?forum=adodotnetdataproviders).  But i *do not* want to create a command and Reader to read the key.

Is there any way to get PrimayKey Column of table *Records* only, using conn.GetSchema ?

Comment: The connection doesn't know the schema of the table. But with a DataReader you can use the method .GetSchemaTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable` and pass PrimaryKeys SchemaGuid.
Apply restrictions on TableName as :

```
DataTable2 = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys, New String() {Nothing, Nothing, TableNm_}) 
For Each TableRow As DataRow In DataTable2.Rows
    If TableRow.Item("PK_NAME").ToString.ToLower = "PrimaryKey".ToLower Then
        Dim  PrimaryKey = TableRow.Item("COLUMN_NAME")
        Dim Ordinal = CShort(TableRow.Item("ORDINAL"))
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DatabaseSchema` from [Kros.Utils.MsAccess](https://github.com/Kros-sk/Kros.Libs/blob/master/Kros.Utils/README.md#msaccess-database-schema)

```
using(var cn = new OleDbConnection("MS Access Connection String"))
{  
  DatabaseSchema schema = DatabaseSchemaLoader.Default.LoadSchema(cn);
  Assert.IsFalse(schema.Tables["Person"].Columns["Id"].AllowNull);
}
```

Contains infromation about Tables, Columns, Indexes, ...